# Detect attribute on method based on string representation of namespace/assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering how to detect an arbitrary attribute on a method if all you know is the fully qualified name of the attribute.

Ex:

```
[MyAttribute]
public void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

Based on a string containing the type name + assembly, can I detect if a method contains the attribute described by the string?

I want to make the detection pluggable and dynamic, so there won't be a reference to the attribute assemblies. The users will add references to the attributes they want to use themselves. I am just looking to implement a generic method to detect any arbitrary method as long as I have its fully qualified name.

Comment: What info do you have about the method?

Comment: I know everything else about the method. I just need to detect if a user defined attribute that I don't know anything about - besides full qualified name

Comment: Things to Google: Reflection. GetMethod. GetAttributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can do the following to find all methods with the given attribute:

```
Type t;

t.GetMembers().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(a => a.GetType().Namespace == "Some.nameSpace" && a.GetType().Name == "AttributeName")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why are you using `GetMembers()` instad of `GetMethods()`?